# Nodejs Rest API login with session cookie

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node.js and express.
I want to login to a rest api.
The api provides a login endpoint, and when I login there I get a response and in the header of the response is an array with multiple fields like:

```
[0]: "JSESSIONID=<id>;path=<path>;HttpOnly"  
[1]: ... 
[2]: "userId=<userid>;Max-Age=1000000000;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly" ...
```

The session-cookie middleware needs a sessionname and keys (Are the keys in the array? Thats what is stored in the var sessionkeys below. Im not sure I'm using this the correct way.)

I wanted to use express and the middleware cookie-session (https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session):

```
app.get('/showorders', function(req, res){

request({
    uri: "...",
    body: postBody,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
    }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    var sessionkeys = response.headers["set-cookie"];

    app.use(cookieSession({
        name: "testsession",
        keys: sessionkeys
    }));
    res.send(response);
});

request({
    uri: "...",
    body: postBody,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'cookie': req.session
    }

}, function (error, response, body) {
    res.send(body);
  });    
});
```

(I removed the url and some other data in this example)

I'm getting a "no user login" error.

The first (login) endpoint gives me a "success" so the first request seems to be okay.
But how does it work in node.js with sessions? How can I create a working session and retrieve data from the rest api with it?